# What kinds of things are appropriate to do in Route.activate

Tags: ember.js

The function seems to be quite isolated.  Meaning, it is invoked with no args so unlike other functions on Route, it does not have 'easy' access to the 'the model and/or controller' for the route.

The [API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate) tells you 'when' this function is invoked, but not much about what you are meant to do in it.

I realize that you can use functions like this.controllerFor, but that seems like it violates what ever type of encapsulation is attempting to be enforced in the activate method, meaning if you were supposed to have access to the controller, it would have been passed as an argument to the function.

If anyone can provide some guidelines for best practices on use of this function, I think it would be helpful to the community.

Comment: Please add your code. It's much easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

`activate` is called once when the route is created for the first time, it's a good place to setup properties that only need to be setup once when the route is created.

`setupController` is called every time the route is hit (with the controller/model). It is a good place for setting up properties that must be generated each time the route is hit.

http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/02/15/ember-1-0-rc.html